# Godot 3d About Velocity

Tags: velocity, godot

I have 3d ball game. The ball continues to go forward.When the left or right rotation key is pressed, it moves in that direction as much as the pressed amount. Ball kinematicbody and using velocity. Everything works perfectly when the road is straight

I am confused what should I change about velocity when switching from straight to curve path.Any help is appreciated

Looking for help with vectors and velocity

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if it is what I'm thinking, you are going to need a flow field.

Comment: You should share the code related to the movement of the ball.